# Return rows with both NA and a value at once

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a df

```
ID <- c(101,102,103,104) 
Status <- c('P','F_Avg','F_Sig',NA) 
df <- data.frame(ID,Status)
```

I am trying to filter the failed ones and return both Pass and NA but I am not able to do so. I know it's a basic question but please bear with me and help me out.

I tried the following

```
df1 <-  sqldf("SELECT * FROM df
              WHERE Status NOT LIKE 'F%'")
```

and it returns only one observation and that is row1 which is 'P' but I also need row4 'NA'.

Comment: declare `NA` as a string.

Comment: This is just an example. I have a bigger datset that has NA's and I want to apply the learning from this example to the bigger one. I don't want to declare as string

Comment: can you do `or is.na(status) = TRUE` in the `where` clause in R?

Comment: is usage of `sqldf` mandatory? It's somewhat trivial to get your desired output in base R.

Comment: `df[df$Status %in% c("P",NA),]` would get you your desired result in base R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 <-  sqldf("SELECT * FROM df
              WHERE (Status NOT LIKE 'F%'
              OR Status IS null)")
```

Output:

```
   ID Status
1 101      P
2 104   <NA>
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !grepl("^F", Status))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sql must be this:

```
SELECT * FROM df
WHERE Status NOT LIKE 'F%'
or status = 'NA'
```

I'm not sure how you achieve that in r.